# EditTextPreference always showing default summary when loaded android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, edittextpreference

I have a preference fragment which has some EditTextPreference items on them. Every time i load the preferences fragment the values displayed are the default values and one the ones stored in sharedPreferences. How can i get these edit texts to always display the text from the sharedPreferences when the menu loads? I tried accessing the sharedPreferences from the fragment using:

```
SharedPreferences def = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
Log.v("Something", def.getString("relay1_name", "no"));
```

but if i try to access any key i just get the default text back. The text input is being saved in sharedPreferences because if i click on an editText the text i set proviously is there allready, its just the summary shows the default text.
Thank you in advance for your help i am most likely missing something very simple.

xml for preferences screen

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory

    android:title="@string/prefs_relay_title">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:dialogTitle="Relay1"
        android:key="relay1_name"
        android:summary="Relay 1"
        android:title="Relay 1"
        android:defaultValue="Relay 1" />

</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

action where fragment is created
    public class PrefsActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment()).commit();    // Load the prefs screen up 
 }
}
```

prefs fragment itself

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

//public static final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.v("PrefsFragment", "Creating prefs fragment");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_xml);

    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

void loadDefaults() {

    SharedPreferences def = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
    Log.v("Something", def.getString("relay1_name", "no"));

}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    if (key.equals("relay1_name")){
        Preference connectionPref = findPreference(key);
        connectionPref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `PreferenceScreen` uses application default shared preferences, while your fragment is using `getActivity().getPreferences()`

Looking at `getPreferences()` in the Activity documentation, it does not retrieve the application shared preferences, but rather the preferences which are private to a particular activity. I think this is not the same as the ones stored by a `PreferenceScreen`.

I might suggest you replace

```
SharedPreferences def = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
```

with

```
SharedPreferences def = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, unfortunatly getSharedPreferences() did not word as it requires a context as an argument which a fragment does not have. However i did solve the problem using - SharedPreferences def = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences(); to access the sharedPreferences of the preference screen directly.